# Is there a way to use less specific Twitter location?

Tags: twitter, geolocation, location

I'm not sure if this would be a setting on my Android phone's Twitter application or on the Twitter website, but I want my tweets to have a location, but not my fine-grained location. Preferably, just identifying the town or city where I'm located, but anything less granular than my exact GPS coordinates to what appears to be a 30 foot accuracy would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using mobile.twitter.com from any mobile safari (on iOS devices) you can choose to use your exact location, or just the location of your nearest neighborhood.

If your twitter client does not support this, try using the browser on your device.

Comment: That'll do for now, and addresses my issue for this question. Now, I'm going to go off and keep looking for a way to do this with the official Twitter Android client.